# Resolving Bitnami MySQL Connectivity Issues

Tags: mysql, azure, bitnami

I have setup Bitnami MySQL service on Azure. The VM is up and I am able to connect to the VM through ssh
like ssh username@HOSTNAME:

I am able to login to the mysql from the prompt like

mysql -uroot -pSOMEPASS
>

Meanwhile I am able to connect this mysql service from a remote host:
mysql -uroot -pPASS -hxxx.xxx.xx.xx

The following error is what I received

ERROr 2003 (HY000); Can't connect to MySQL Server on xxx.xxx.xx.xx

I tried commenting out the the bind-address in the /opt/bitnami/mysql/my.cnf

and tried giving the value for bind-address as 0:0:0:0 & also removing the variable.

To ensure the mysql port is up or not I gave the following comamnd

netstat -tln

tcp6 0 0 :::3306 :::* LISTEN

the above results mean port is and listening

In terms of file permission related, I entered the following ones

chmod 777 /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp
chmod 755 /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
chown -R root:root /opt/bitnami/mysq/tmp
chown mysql:root /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/
sudo chmod 777 /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp
sudo chmod 755 /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
sudo chown root:root /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp
sudo chown mysql:root /opt/bitnami/mysql/data

Also added
skip-grant-tables in my.cnf

I also performed the following the query in the mysql

GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'SOMEPASSWORD';

Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked that the cloud firewall ports are open?

Comment: I added the mysql port to Azure VM's Inbound rules as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to your Bitnami MySQL, follow these steps:

1.Make sure your Azure VM have a **public IP address**.

2.Open port 3306 to NSG **inbound rules**:
[image]
3.Edit the file `/opt/bitnami/mysql/my.cnf` and **comment out** this line by placing a hash(#) symbol at the beginning, save it.

```
#bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

4.At the server console, **allow** remote access to the MySQL database server using the MySQL command line client. Use the following command, remembering to replace PASSWORD with the application password from the first step:

```
/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p -e "grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'PASSWORD' with grant option";
```

5.**Restart** the MySQL server:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart mysql
```

Now, you can remote connect to your bitnami mysql.

Here is my result:
[image]

Hope this helps.